# Different property types for different product categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible in WordPress Woocommerce to input for different product categories different properties, for example for laptops

- speed
- memory size
- number of cores..

for mobile phones

- screen size
- type of SIM card...

I googled with all the terms I know but no luck. Can someone please point me to a help/tutorial or plugin if something like that is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

personally advise to create "speed", "memory size", "numbers of cores" as category and use this fantastic plugin https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/ for create a filter page, where user can search by parameters.

Let me know.